# Yield não retorna dados

Tags: c#, html, yield, enumerable, html-agility-pack

Ao executar a chamada do método, deveria ser retornada um Enumerable de componentes HTML.

Estou utilizando o [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) para ler um arquivo HTML. O mesmo método funciona como esperado, ao remover o `yield` e adicionar manualmente em uma lista

```
    HtmlNode slideCineAll = GetNodeById(cinema, "slide-cine-all");
    HtmlNode section = GetNodeByName(slideCineAll, "section");
    IEnumerable<HtmlNode> articles = GetNodesByName(section, "article");

    private static IEnumerable<HtmlNode> GetNodesByName(HtmlNode root, string node)
    {
        foreach (HtmlNode link in root.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (link.Name.Equals(node))
            {
                yield return link;
            }
        }
    }

    private static List<HtmlNode> GetNodesByNameList(HtmlNode root, string node)
    {
        List<HtmlNode> nodes = new List<HtmlNode>();
        foreach (HtmlNode link in root.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (link.Name.Equals(node))
            {
                nodes.Add(link);
            }
        }
        return nodes;
    }
```

#### Este é o resultado armazenado na variável ao executar o método

```
{ConsoleApplication1.Program.GetNodesByName}
node: null
root: null
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode>.Current: null
System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current: null
```

#### Resultado esperado

```
values
Count = 20
[0]: Name: "article"}
.
.
.
values[0]
_attributes: {HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttributeCollection}
_childnodes: {HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection}
_endnode: Name: "article"}
.
.
.
```

#### Essa é a estrutura que estou percorrendo, através do método `GetNodesByName` ou `GetNodesByNameList` eu consigo recuperar uma lista de qualquer nó da estrutura `html`

```
<div id="slide-cine-all">
<section>
    <article>
        <!--mais elementos-->
    </article>
    <article>
        <!--mais elementos-->
    </article>
    <article>
        <!--mais elementos-->
    </article>
    <article>
        <!--mais elementos-->
    </article>
    <article>
        <!--mais elementos-->
    </article>
    <article>
        <!--mais elementos-->
    </article>
</section>
</div>
```

Como descrito no começo, o método GetNodesByNameList retornar todos os itens, nesse caso do tipo *article* encontrados na estrutura do arquivo, mas o mesmo não acontece quando utilizo o yield.

Comment: Como não sabemos qual o resultado esperado, fica difícil ajudar. Sequer estamos vendo o código que produz a variável que você está se referenciando. Dê mais informações para nós entendermos o problema.

Comment: Adicionei mais algumas informações.

Comment: Melhorou bastante mas ainda não há informações suficientes para identificar o que está errado. Não sei por exemplo para que está servindo o `GetNodesByNameList` para definir o problema. Mas certamente falta informações para saber como você espera chegar no resultado esperado, quais os dados sendo usados para produzir este resultado. Por outro lado, talvez possa descrever melhor qual o problema que está encontrando para que alguém possa lhe apresentar uma solução.

Comment: adicionei mais algumas informações e os dados utilizados

Comment: Só quando procura o "article" dá o problema? Ou com "section" também? Existem outras chamadas antes? Como está este `GetNodeById`? Está difícil ver o todo. O problema pode estar ocorrendo por problemas anteriores ou em partes que você não está demonstrando. Mas eu acho, por exemplo que o método com `yield` funciona mas não retorna o que **você** espera, aí vai dando problemas em cadeia, Mas ainda é só um chute, não sei se entendi todo o problema.

Comment: as duas primeiras linhas estão funcionando corretamente. Observe que o método `GetNodesByNameList` tem a mesma estrutura do método `GetNodesByName`, mas no caso ele utiliza o `yield`, utilizando a lista todos esses articles sao retornados e com `yield` isso não acontece. Ficou mais claro agora?

Comment: Acho que entendi o problema. Me parece que você não entende o funcionamento do `yield`. Ele não funciona como parece que você espera. Você sabe que ele é um `return`, que ele encera a execução na primeira interação do `for each`? Claro que a interação pode ser retomada de onde parou na próxima chamada. Não sei bem qual é o seu objetivo mas me parece que neste caso você não pode usar o `yield`.

Comment: A primeira chamada do método está retornado a "section" e mais nada. Aí você vai procurar por "article" e não tem o que achar. Provavelmente acharia se chamasse o método procurando pela "section" mais vezes, aí leria todo o nó. Sem o `yield` vem todo o nó, por isto funciona. Você tem que saber que um método que retorna um `yield` dentro de um  *loop* qq executará um passo deste laço em cada chamada ao método. Se quer que venha 10 `link`s, terá que chamar o `GetNodesByName` 10 vezes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Veja a [documentação do `yield return`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Ele não faz o que parece ser o que você espera dele. A parte do `return` é importante. Quando chega nesta linha, ele termina a execução do método. Portanto o seu código só retorna um elemento dos nós existentes no seu XML.

Tem como retornar mais. Você precisa chamar o método mais vezes. Cada chamada executará uma nova linha de onde parou. O `yield` cria algo chamado [generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) ([em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)#C.23)). Ele controla a execução através de um estado oculto que determina em que ponto de uma enumeração o programa está executando, então a chamada consegue continuar de onde parou. Note que ele retorna um tipo enumerável e não o tipo do que você quer em si. Esta estrutura enumerável é que controla a continuidade da execução de onde parou.

Então seu problema é que você pega **um único link** do nó e tenta em seguida fazer uma busca dentro dele como se existisse outros elementos deste nó. É claro que não existem outros elementos, você ainda não os leu. Aí é onde dá o problema.

No outro método que funciona por não ter o `yield`, o *loop* é executado por completo e varre todos os nós e retorna uma árvore mais completa que depois pode ser pesquisada sem problema. Tudo o que você precisa está lá.

Não deu para entender o problema como um todo mas acho que neste caso o `yield` está atrapalhando. E aconselho usá-lo apenas quando entender totalmente seu funcionamento. Ele é excelente mas não é solução para todos os problemas. Não estou dizendo que este problema não possa beneficiar-se dele (gerar eficiência por não varrer toda a estrutura e sim só o que é necessário no momento) mas precisaria mudar algumas coisas no código que consome este método. Na prática quando você usa um `yield`, a grosso modo, você terá um outro *loop* externo para varrer toda a estrutura que está pesquisando (claro que dá para fazer manualmente também de forma repetida).

Sugiro inspecionar os dados e acompanhar a execução no *debug* para entender melhor o que está acontecendo com o código. Pode ajudar aprender sobre o funcionamento do `yield` e ver com clareza seu problema, e quem sabe até achar uma solução melhor. Ou ainda explicar de outra forma o problema que eu não consegui enxergar melhor que isto.

Para ajudar entender execute o seguinte código retirado desta [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39496/221800):

```
public void Consumer() {
    foreach(int i in Integers()) {
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
    }
}

public IEnumerable<int> Integers() {
    yield return 1;
    yield return 2;
    yield return 4;
    yield return 8;
    yield return 16;
    yield return 16777216;
}
```

Ou este desta [resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1407192/221800):

```
// Display powers of 2 up to the exponent 8:
foreach (int i in Power(2, 8)) {
    Console.Write("{0} ", i);
}

public static IEnumerable<int> Power(int number, int exponent) {
    int counter = 0;
    int result = 1;
    while (counter++ < exponent) {
        result = result * number;
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/Yield.cs).

Notou que o código consumidor acaba sempre tendo que repetir as chamadas, de uma certa forma as repetições existentes no código gerador (do `yield`)? A grande vantagem do `yield` para a maioria das situações é criar abstrações melhores.

Veja uma [explicação rápida de como é o *internals* do comando](https://www.dotnetperls.com/yield). E uma [explicação mais completa](https://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/behind-the-scenes-of-the-c-yield-keyword/).

Comment: Entendi. Isso é semelhante ao LINQ, onde a consulta é armazenada na variável, e os dados em si são recuperados quando a variável que contém a consulta é utilizada. Isso passou pela minha cabeça quando vi que a variável tinha uma referência ao método `GetNodesByName` em vez de um `IEnumerable<HtmlNode>`. É isso que está descrito?

Comment: O LINQ é todo baseado no `yield`. Não sei se entendi sua pergunta. Seria complicado para eu testar aqui mas dá para mudar o código e fazer a busca interna por todos os elementos da "section" dentro do próprio método quando está buscando por "article". Não é tão simples, principalmente de forma genérica, mas é possível.

Comment: Era exatamente isso @bigown. Testei agora, e funcionou. Antes de postar a pergunta eu parei a execução quando vi que o objeto não tinha o que eu esperava, mas é como você descreveu, eu ainda não tinha lido os elementos. Se tivesse deixado o código executando, nem teria percebido. Mas serviu de aprendizado. :)